# Finding the maximum and minimum values of a function in 3 variables subject to a given constraint using Lagrange multiplier

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

Question: Use Lagrange Multiplier to determine the maximum values of $f(x,y,z) = x^2
+ y^2 + z^2$ subject to constraint $xyz = 4$.

I do not know how to solve this, I got the expression $x^2 = y^2 = z^2$ then what should I do next?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you know the method of Lagrange multipliers?
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With

$$
f = x^2+y^2+z^2
$$

forming the Lagrangian

$$
L(x,y,z,\lambda) = f+\lambda(x y z-4)
$$

and determining the stationary points by solving

$$
2x+\lambda y z = 0\\
2y+\lambda x z = 0\\
2z+\lambda x y = 0\\
x y x - 4 = 0
$$

we get at

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
x & y & z & f\\
 -2^{2/3} & -2^{2/3} & 2^{2/3} & 6 \sqrt[3]{2} \\
 -2^{2/3} & 2^{2/3} & -2^{2/3} & 6 \sqrt[3]{2} \\
 2^{2/3} & -2^{2/3} & -2^{2/3} & 6 \sqrt[3]{2} \\
 2^{2/3} & 2^{2/3} & 2^{2/3} & 6 \sqrt[3]{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

NOTE

The system to solve is equivalent to

$$
2x^2+\lambda x y z = 0\\
2y^2+\lambda x y z = 0\\
2z^2+\lambda x y z = 0\\
x y x - 4 = 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

Since you already got $x^2=y^2=z^2$, use the constraint $xyz=4$. Square the constraint, and you get $x^2y^2z^2=16$. Plugging in your result, you get $x^6=2^4$. Then $x^2=2^\frac 43=2\sqrt[3]2$. Now using your result again in $f(x,y,z) =x^2+y^2+z^2$, you get the maximum as $3\cdot 2\sqrt[3]2=6\sqrt[3]2$/

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The trick is to define a function $g(x, y, z) = f(x, y, z) -\lambda(xyz - 4)$ which takes the same values as $f(x, y, z)$ as long as the constraint is satisfied; $\lambda$ is the Lagrance multiplier. Now you maximize $g(x, y, z)$ without having to worry about the constraint. You do that by taking the partial derivatives wrt. $x, y, z$ and setting them equal to 0 to find the extrema. That's three equation in *four* unknowns ($x, y, z, \lambda$), but the constraint equation comes to the rescue providing a fourth equation (alternatively, you can consider $g$ as a function of $x, y, z\ AND\ \lambda$ and in addition, take the partial derivative of $g$ wrt $\lambda$ and set that equal to 0; but you can easily see that that's the constraint equation). Now solve them for the four unknowns and substitute the values in $f(x,y,z)$ to find the extreme values of $f$. You then have to worry about which one(s) give you the maximum value, but that should be easy: there is a finite number of solutions, so you can enumerate them and figure out which one(s) give you the maximum value.